# jetty websockets send binary data (image)

Tags: java, javascript, websocket, jetty, binary-data

I am trying to use Jetty 8.1.2 WebSockets to send some binary data (an image) to a javascript client.

websockets java code:

```
BufferedImage image = getTheImage();

ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", baos);
baos.flush();
byte[] imageInBytes = baos.toByteArray();
baos.close();

socket.getConnection().sendMessage(imageInBytes, 0, imageInBytes.length);
```

javascript code:

```
binarySocket.onmessage = function(event) {
if (event.data instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
    var bytearray = new Uint8Array(event.data);

    var tempcanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    tempcanvas.height = imageheight;
    tempcanvas.width = imagewidth;
    var tempcontext = tempcanvas.getContext('2d');

    var imgdata = tempcontext.getImageData(0, 0, imagewidth,imageheight);
    var imgdatalen = imgdata.data.length;

    for ( var i = 8; i < imgdatalen; i++) {
        imgdata.data[i] = bytearray[i];
    }

    tempcontext.putImageData(imgdata, 0, 0);

    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.height = imageheight;
    img.width = imagewidth;
    img.src = tempcanvas.toDataURL();
    chatdiv = document.getElementById('chatdiv');
    chatdiv.appendChild(img);
    chatdiv.innerHTML = chatdiv.innerHTML + "<br />";
}
```

};

The code is fine if I write the image on disk, but if I try to display the image on an HTML page, I get some random coloured image.
I am probably encoding the image in a wrong way.

Any idea how to send the image as binary data and display it with javascript?

Comment: Why would you send this image over a websocket instead of just writing a servlet that can serve it normally?

Comment: I know I can use a servlet for this. This is just for the sake of learning websockets.

Answer (score 3):

You are right. The problem is the image encoding.

Replace:

```
img.src = tempcanvas.toDataURL();
```

to

```
img.src = tempcanvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
```

The default format is PNG.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that this is wrong:

```
for ( var i = 8; i < imgdatalen; i++) {
    imgdata.data[i] = bytearray[i];
}
```

you can't just put the data from **bytearray** in **imgdata.data** as bytearray is encoded (jpeg) in your case. No surprise you were getting random pixels on some of the canvas (in the upper side of it, i guess). You need to encode the bytearray to a [data url](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) and just set that as src for the image. No canvas needed.